# upstart-monitor with CLI option fails to start in Ubuntu Server 13.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart, ubuntu-13.04

When I try starting upstart-monitor on Ubuntu Server 13.04. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/upstart-monitor", line 195, in <module>
class UpstartEventsGui(Gtk.Window):
NameError: name 'Gtk' is not defined
```

This happens after I type

```
upstart-monitor -n
```

on the Linux shell? Could anyone assist with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 15, systemd has been the preferred init and during past 4+ years nobody bothered to fix the bug.

For those of us still running Upstart, there is my patch to fix this in the original [Bug #1235245 upstart-monitor cannot run without gtk libraries installed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/1235245).